# Python regex ignore empty lines

Tags: python, regex, filtering

I have data with the following structure:

```
[TimingPoints]
21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0
21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
23547,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0

24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0
27657,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0
29301,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
30123,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
30945,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0

32588,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
34232,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
35876,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
36698,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
37520,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
42451,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0


[HitObjects]
256,192,17794,12,0,20876,0:0:0:0:
159,96,21082,6,0,B|204:120|204:120|254:103|254:103|305:130|355:102,1,210
409,27,22725,2,0,P|446:96|405:179,1,171.499994766236
269,284,23547,2,0,B|317:250|324:193|324:193|328:220|350:236,1,146.999995513916
```

I'd like to read all lines under [TimingPoints] before [HitObjects] in a list.
Empty lines should be ignored.
So the final list should contain:

```
21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0
21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
23547,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0
27657,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0
29301,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
30123,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
30945,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
32588,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
34232,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
35876,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
36698,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
37520,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
42451,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
```

I tried it with the following regex pattern:
`\[TimingPoints\]((.|\n)*)\[HitObjects]` but it does not ignore the empty lines.
How can I match the lines to get what is described above?
Also how can I load all the matched lines in a list with python?

Comment: Is this coming from a CSV/plaintext file?  Perhaps use `with open(myfile.csv, 'r') as f: text = f.readlines()`.  Then, you can use a conditional statement to remove all lines in the list after HitObjects.  Or use Pandas to do your filtering ...

Comment: @S3DEV its a plain text file. Do I really have to manually remove all the empty lines manually? Isn't there a simple regex one-liner that filters accordingly and stores the lines in a list?

Comment: first get text and later remove empty lines. Empty lines usually meas `\n\n` which you can replace with `\n` - `text = text.replace('\n\n', '\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get me wrong, I'm a huge fan of regex and use it daily.  But it's a bit heavy for this task.

1) Read the file into a `list` and strip any whitespace (including new line characters), and drop the line if it's empty
2) Index to find '[HitObjects]' and trim from the list, along with the header
3) Done

#### Sample Code:

```
path = './timing.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    text = [i.strip() for i in f if i.strip()]

# Keep only rows between the headers of interest.
result = text[text.index('[TimingPoints]')+1:text.index('[HitObjects]')]
```

#### Output:

```
['21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0',
 '21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '23547,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '27657,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '29301,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '30123,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '30945,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '32588,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '34232,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '35876,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '36698,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '37520,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0',
 '42451,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0']
```

Comment: However, this would assume there is no data before? Keep in mind there can be other data before `[TimingPoints]`. So we also need to figure out the index of that line before we extract the data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the biggest regex fan you'll ever meet.  Here's a straightforward way of doing it without regexes:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.1/bin/python3  

# Works on CPython 3.1 through 3.9  

"""Keep lines between [TimingPoints] and [HitObjects], elliding empty lines."""  


def main():  
    """Read input and write actual-output."""  
    display = False                            
    with open('input', 'r') as infile, open('actual-output', 'w') as outfile:  
        for line in infile:                                                    
            line_sans_n = line.rstrip('\n')  
            if not line_sans_n:              
                # Skip blank lines  
                continue            
            if line_sans_n == '[HitObjects]':  
                display = False                
            if display:           
                print(line_sans_n, file=outfile)  
            if line_sans_n == '[TimingPoints]':   
                display = True
```

HTH